# Using javascript or CSS to change the color of the input area when I hover the mouse on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<form>
    <input id="b2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name." name="name" maxlength="300">
    <br>
    <button id="b1" type="button name" >Submit</button>
</form>
<script> 
    document.getElementById("b1").hover = function() {
        document.getElementById("b2").style.color="blue";
    }; 
</script>
```

- Input with id `b2`,
- The button with id `b1`,
- Hover on `b1`, change the color on `b2`

Comment: Post the JS code of what you did till now.

Comment: <script>
 document.getElementById("b1").hover = function() { 
 
 document.getElementById("b2").style.color="blue";

 };
</script>

Comment: And I found I could hover on one BUTTON and change the css on another BUTTON by using pure css                                                                      #button1:hover + #button2
{
 border:solid 1px #ccc; 
}   But don't know how to make change on an input

Comment: Probably this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css?rq=1

Comment: Thank you alfuco, your link is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
document.getElementById('b1').onmouseover = function(){
    document.getElementById('b2').style.color = 'red';
};
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="b2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name." name="name" maxlength="300">
    <br>
    <button id="b1" type="button name">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Chris: please accept and vote me up [http://stackoverflow.com/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input id="b2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name." name="name" maxlength="300">
    <br>
    <button id="b1" type="button name" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

*Executed when hovered by the mouse*

```
$("#b1").hover(function() {
    $("#b2").css("color","red");
});
```

*Executed when hovered by the mouse, stops when unhovered*

```
$("#b1").mouseover(function() {
    $("#b2").css("color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
<form>
<input id="b2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name." name="name" maxlength="300">

<button id="b1" type="button name" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

script.

```
$("#b1").hover(function(){
  $('#b2').css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function(){
$('#b2').css("background-color", "pink");

 });
```

here is the fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/z8vr6fwu/

Comment: Hey Jean, this looks very nice as well.